# October CMS Install As A Subdirectory - /backend Not Found, Nginx Configuration Issue?

Tags: nginx, octobercms

I have an existing website that uses laravel 4.2. I am attempting to install October CMS in the /blog subdirectory (to function as a blog and help section only), but something in nginx setup incorrectly. I did the October CMS install wizard, and am able to get the /blog/index.php page to appear correctly. The issue is when I attempt to login to the backend (/blog/backend), I get a 404 page. Below is my virtual-host nginx configuration for this site:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_site;
    root /home/vagrant/my_site/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my_site.app-error.log error;
    rewrite_log on;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    # October CMS rewrites
    location blog {
        root /home/vagrant/my_site/public/blog;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    rewrite ^/blog/themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/bootstrap/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/config/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/vendor/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/storage/cms/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/storage/logs/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/storage/framework/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/storage/temp/protected/.* /blog/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/blog/storage/app/uploads/protected/.* /blog/index.php break;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I can get the /blog/backend page to appear (albeit unstyled with css/js) if I add the following directive:

```
rewrite ^/blog /blog/index.php break;
```

Note that with the above rewrite directive, the assets for the /blog/index.php page do come back with a result of 404, so the /blog/index.php page is unstyled as well. However, if I remove the above directive, the links will work again.

I am new to nginx and setting up October CMS and cannot figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use October CMS but looking at your config, I don't think all those rewrites are needed and you just need to set up the try_files part properly.

Also looks like you need to think about what exactly is your root folder. I am assuming here that it is `/home/vagrant/my_site/public/blog`

Given that, this should work for you:

```
    Server {

    ....

    # Generally better to define root at server level
    root /home/vagrant/my_site/public/blog;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # Use this instead if root folder is /home/vagrant/my_site/public
    #location /blog {
    #   try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    #}


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: The root folder is correct as originally noted `/home/vagrant/my_site/public`  I am trying to add October CMS onto an existing laravel application where the October CMS will handle only the blog and help sections of the application. The rewrites are as noted in the conguration document on the OctoberCMS site:  https://octobercms.com/docs/help/installation#nginx-configuration

Comment: The suggested config seems a bit suspect as it doesn't have anything to say about a php location and the rewrites seem to just send everything to index.php which generally replicates what the try_files will do. Not so sure whoever wrote that really understands Nginx. Try my suggest config and see. I posted options for whatever root config you have. You can also add the rewrites if you want. They do no real harm even if it turns out they are actually not needed.

Comment: Ok - it looks like your `location blog { .... }` fix did the trick (along with removing `/blog` from the `rewrite` directives (that was my nginx ineptitude at work there. Fixed now - thanks! (will award bounty as soon as they allow me).